# reverse for success_url on Django Class Based View complain about circular import

Tags: django, redirect, django-views

When using method-based view, redirecting with `reverse` didn't complain about this and can still find the root url conf. But, in class-based views, it complain:

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /blog/new-post/

The included urlconf 'blog.urls' does not appear to have any
patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the
issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

My class is defined like this:

```
class BlogCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/new-post.html'
    success_url = reverse('blog:list-post')
```

How to properly use `reverse` for `success_url` in class-based views? Thanks.

**PS:** And I'm interested in why it's need to restart `runserver` after this error (not like an error like `TemplateDoesNotExists` which is no need to restart `runserver`)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Using `reverse` in your method works because `reverse` is called when the view is run.

```
def my_view(request):
    url = reverse('blog:list-post')
    ...
```

If you overrride `get_success_url`, then you can still use `reverse`, because `get_success_url` calls `reverse` when the view is run.

```
class BlogCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    ...
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('blog:list-post')
```

However, you can't use `reverse` with `success_url`, because then `reverse` is called when the module is imported, before the urls have been loaded.

Overriding `get_success_url` is one option, but the easiest fix is to use [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead of reverse.

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
# from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy  # old import for Django < 1.10

class BlogCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    ...
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:list-post')
```

To answer your final question about restarting runserver, the `ImproperlyConfigured` error is different from `TemplateDoesNotExists` because it occurs when the Django application is loaded.

Comment: `reverse_lazy()` works fine with **Django 1.9**, I have tried, `reverse()` throws an exception.

Answer (score 15):

Try using [`reverse_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead of [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) in your CBV. Its a lazily evaluated version of `reverse`. It won't execute until the value is needed.

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class BlogCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = Blog
    template_name = 'blog/new-post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:list-post')
```