# Getting mistake after creating success_url with CreateView class

Tags: python, django, generics, view

Sorry for my bad English in advance.

I'm trying to discover django, so I decided to write my own sign in/sign up views.

So I just wrote something like that -

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'auth/user_create_form.html'
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']
```

So, it's basically working with GET requests. We can see the form on specified url.

But after altering all fields and submitting form, I've got a mistake what suggested to specify *get_absolute_url* for model to redirect after submitting. So I decided to give success_url to RegisterView -

```
class RegisterView(CreateView):

    template_name = 'auth/user_create_form.html'
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'password', 'email']
    success_url = reverse('words:main_page')
```

And got a mistake

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 600, in url_patterns
    iter(patterns)
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 892, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 118, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 419, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 76, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 412, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 598, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yegor/projects/word_collector/word_collector/urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    path('', include('words.urls'))
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/python@3.9/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/yegor/projects/word_collector/words/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from words.views import MainView, RegisterView, LoginView
  File "/home/yegor/projects/word_collector/words/views.py", line 12, in <module>
    class RegisterView(CreateView):
  File "/home/yegor/projects/word_collector/words/views.py", line 17, in RegisterView
    success_url = reverse('words:main_page')
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 54, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 526, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 460, in _populate
    for url_pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/yegor/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/word-collector-g9LS8W6v-py3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 607, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name)) from e
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'word_collector.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

I'm sure that urlconf is great. Where this thing getting circular import? And how I should use **success_url**?

By the way, if I assign POST method to class -

```
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.success_url = reverse('words:main_page')
        return super().post(*args, **kwargs)
```

then everything work properly, but I still don't understand why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reverse for success\_url on Django Class Based View complain about circular import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275574/reverse-for-success-url-on-django-class-based-view-complain-about-circular-impor)